# Background gets smaller and divs get under each other while changing screen size

Tags: css, html, background, screen

AS you can see from the title I have two questions.
First question is very simple, I have this css code for the background:

```
body{
display:block;
background:url(file:///C:/Users/Abdallah/Desktop/Background%20images/Fotor0512155059.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position-y:27px;
margin:0;
}
```

All I want is that when I get the screen smaller(CTRL -) the background stays on full screen and does NOT get smaller so there will be white space.
Second question is simple too.
I have some divs near each other and I want when I get the screen bigger(CTRL +) the divs stays near each other and does NOT get under each other.

Here's example(http://jsfiddle.net/njmFT/) if you get the screen bigger (CTRL +) the black boxes get under each others, if you get the screen smaller (CTRL -) the background get smaller and you can see white space.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide a demonstration of your problem with [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: Here's example(http://jsfiddle.net/njmFT/) if you get the screen bigger (CTRL +) the black boxes get under each others, if you get the screen smaller (CTRL -) the background get smaller and you can see white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your first question, I think you might be looking for

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: #ffffff url(file:///C:/Users/Abdallah/Desktop/Background%20images/Fotor0512155059.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

It's the `background-size` property that's doing the business but be careful - the support through the browsers is only relatively recent.

Also, remember to us an absolute or relative URL for the img resource when you upload it otherwise you will see the background image but your visitors won't!

Working on your second problem now!

EDIT.

OK... some ideas about your second question

I think if you start using percentages instead of fixed pixel widths for your boxes. Try something like

```
.box{
    background-color:#000;
    width:20%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 2%;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

BTW - you shouldn't use multiple identical IDs in the same page - use `class="box"` and `.box{}` instead of `id="box"` and `#box{}`

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/em5Ga/

Sorry - bad link to fiddle - updated!

Comment: Man, thank you very much, I understood every word you said and you solved my problem 100% THANK YOU!

Comment: BTW, I edited your body tag because you were shifting the background position manually to compensate (I think) for the body padding which may easily vary from browser to browser. It's better practice to simple 'switch off' margin *and* padding for the whole body tag if you don't need it. In fact, some people like to start off with `html,body{padding:0;margin:0}`

Comment: Regarding the second issue, you could also try `white-space: nowrap; overflow: auto;` CSS regarding `body`.

Comment: for the second issue I have got some problems.
Actually it's not the original code, the original code of my divs contains padding and margin so I can't set it as different value, here's my code:
`.menutext{
font-family:Helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif;
font-size:16;
display:inline-block;
border:solid;
border-color:#aaa #ccc;
border-width:0 0 5 6;
padding:6 40 7 40;
margin:7 15;
box-shadow:-1px 2px 5px #404040;
}`
BTW I can't upvote because I have low reputation :/

Comment: @Doug check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer

Comment: Looking at your CSS, you have to remember that all of these extra bits and bobs add to the width of your element so, for example, `div{width:17%;padding:0 2%;margin:0 2%}` will create a div that is 21% (17% + (2% + 2% padding)) the width of the containing element with a further 2% margin on each side. In theory this should then cover 25% the width of the containing element (or body, in this case). So, to get this answer working you need to add everything in %age - the element width, padding, margin, even the border width, and keep a running total as you go.

Comment: Seer I'm not new I know how working on stackoverflow is and I would accept his answer without any problem

Comment: Thanks @Seer - I too am I bit of a newbie around here - I've been harvesting help from well-intending developers for 12 months without giving much back to the community - just trying to inject a little positive karma back into the system... Sorry if I came across as a rep whore ;-)