# Divs stays inline-block on getting the screen bigger

Tags: css, html

I have some divs near each other in one block and I want them to stay in the same block(line) on getting the screen bigger(CTRL +), here's my code (http://fiddle.jshell.net/YDyfy/),
CSS:

```
    #menu{
width:100%;
height:40px;
margin:auto;
padding:0 0 12;
background:url(file:///C:/Users/Windows7/Desktop/imgbg.jpg) repeat 0 0 #f8f8f8;
border:1 solid;
border-width:0 1 1;
box-shadow:0px 1px 10px #000;
text-align:center;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
.menutext{
font-family:Helvetica neue,Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,Sans-serif;
font-size:16;
display:inline-block;
border:solid;
border-color:#aaa #ccc;
border-width:0 0 5 6;
padding:6 40 7 40;
margin:7 15;
box-shadow:-1px 2px 5px #404040;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="menu">
<a href="#div1" class="scroll"><div class="menutext" linkId="div1">Description</div></a>
<a href="#div2" class="scroll"><div class="menutext" linkId="div2">Shipping and payments</div></a>
<a href="#div3" class="scroll"><div class="menutext" linkId="div3">Seller information</div></a>
<a href="#div4" class="scroll"><div class="menutext" linkId="div4">Feedback</div></a>
</div>
```

Simply, I want when the screen get bigger divs stays in the same line/block

Comment: are you sure its not the padding thats causing that? and do you want to keep it on one rule ? or more rules?

Comment: Did you not see my additional comment I posted in your previous thread where you asked this same question? I think it's down to setting fixed pixel widths where everything needs to be done in %ages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520783/background-gets-smaller-and-divs-get-under-each-other-while-changing-screen-size/16521020#16521020

Comment: One rule, inline-block

Comment: sorry Doug that didn't help me

Answer (score 1):

Use `white-space:nowrap` on the container ([updated Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/YDyfy/1/)).

Your question is very unclear, so don't shoot me if this isn't what you are looking for.

As a general sidenote, you should never nest block level elements such as `<div>` inside inline elements such as `<a>`. If anything those should be `<span>` elements.

Comment: Good solution - however be careful when you reach full width because the menu will escape of the side of the page forcing people to scroll sideways to reach the end of the menu.

Comment: You did it bro, thank you very much, @doug you gave me same solution, thank you too!

Comment: I got another problem :/ I can't see the divs when I CTRL +, it should give me scrollbar that let me scroll to the divs so I can see it, what's the solution?

Comment: Add `overflow:auto` to the parent as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused. You want them to appear all on the same line? Or on separate lines?

If you want them all on one line when the window increases, then I see no problem with the fiddle you provided.

If you want them all on separate lines, change the `display` attribute to `block` in your CSS.

Comment: in fiddle it displays under each other, just press CTRL - two times so you can see them in the same line, I want them to stay like that all the time also if I got the screen bigger(if I pressed CTRL +)

Comment: @MhmdRobaee You are aware that this behaviour with ctrl -/+ is highly depedendant on the user's browser size right?

Answer (score 0):

You miss some px in padding, margin and font, I think due to this you got the issue.
Use font size in percentage or EM.